# Flatten output list from sympy

Tags: python, combinations, sympy, nested-lists

I'm calculating a whole bunch of scenarios, involving the geometry of a floor slab. Pretty much what I need to do is iterate every single case for lengths up to 200 meters, and thicknesses up to 120 cm. Which I solved using sympy.

Except there's this annoying bit that I'm sure has a simple solution, but I can't figure it out. This is how I generate my different scenarios for calculating:

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_combinations,multiset_permutations,iproduct

dims_lw = range(1000,200500,500)
dims_th = range(50,130,10)

dimensions = multiset_combinations(dims_lw,2)
combinations_dim = iproduct(dimensions,dims_th)
```

For side dimensions, a combination of every possible number from 1 to 200 (combinations to cut down the number of scenarios, because 10 x 200m is the same as 200 x 10m). Then cartesian product to get every combination for a series of possible thicknesses.

And when I do `print(list(dimensions))` to see what I'm generating, I get this:

```
[([1000, 1500], 50), ([1000, 2000], 50), ([1000, 1500], 100), ([1000, 2500], 50), ([1000, 2000], 100) ...]
```

Which is sort of what I want. Except exactly what I want is the same thing, but without the nested list. (1000, 1500, 50), (1000, 2000, 50), and so forth so I don't have to mess with more indexes and subindexes than I need to, later on.

Question is, how to I turn my current output, into that one I want? Or avoid my original problem altogether?

Answer (score 0):

To flatten the output use the `flatten` function:

```py
>>> from sympy import flatten
>>> x = [([1,2], 3),([4,5], 6)]
>>> [flatten(i) for i in x]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> [tuple(flatten(i)) for i in x]
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```